# Rewrite code to be with less procedures in Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, procedure

I wrote a program, that given two numbers that specify a range, should return the number (count) of numbers in that range that represented in `octal` form consist of a number of identical digits. For example `72->111` meets this criteria, because all the digits are the same. Examples of output:

`(hw11 1 8) -> 7`,`(hw11 1 9) -> 8`,`(hw11 1 18) -> 9`,`(hw11 1 65) -> 14`, and so on...

My problem is that to be correct my program must define only 2 procedures, and at the moment I have much more than that and have no idea how to make them less. So any help with rewriting the code is welcomed :). The code is below:

---

```
(define (count-digits n)
  (if (<= n 0) 
      0 
      (+ 1 (count-digits (quotient n 10)))))

(define (toOct n)
  (define (helper n octNumber i)
    (if(<= n 0)
       octNumber
       (helper (quotient n 8) 
               (+ octNumber 
                  (* (expt 10 i) 
                     (remainder n 8)))
               (+ i 1))))
  (helper n 0 0))

(define (samedigits n)
  (define (helper n i)
    (if (<= n 0)
        #t 
        (if (not (remainder n 10) i))
        #f
        (helper (quotient n 10) i))))

(helper n (remainder n 10))
)

(define (hw11 a b)
  (define (helper a x count)
    (if (> a x)
        count
        (if (samedigits (toOct x))
            (helper a (- x 1) (+ count 1))
            (helper a (- x 1) count))))
  (helper a b 0))
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile and is not formatted.

Comment: Without proper identation LISP code is unreadable. Now that it is you can easily see that `samedigits` has some errors. One parenthesis is ending the inner if prematurely. If you use an IDE or editor with bracket matching this wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have restrictions and you didn't state which Scheme implementation you're using; the following is an example that has been tested on Racket and Guile:

```
(define (hw11 a b)
  (define (iter i count)
    (if (<= i b)
        (let* ((octal (string->list (number->string i 8))) 
               (allc1 (make-list (length octal) (car octal))))
          (iter (+ i 1) (if (equal? octal allc1) (+ count 1) count)))
        count))
  (iter a 0))
```

Testing:

```
> (hw11 1 8)
7
> (hw11 1 9)
8
> (hw11 1 18)
9
> (hw11 1 65)
14
```